# heroku mongohq and mongoid Mongo::ConnectionFailure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, heroku, mongoid, mongohq

UPDATE 9th june 2012:

Setup with mongoid 3.0.0.rc at heroku, see this gist: https://gist.github.com/2900804

UPDATE 22th jan 2011:

Uri now takes precedence in mongoid.yml

https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/issue/266

UPDATE 12th aug 2010: Although I got an accepted answer 6th may from Jackues Crocker, there are aspects of this issue that makes it easy to mess up! It happened to me yet again and I decided to research the mongoid source code. So, here it goes:

Currently, ***host: port: name/database:* settings TAKE PRECEDENCE OVER the *uri:* setting.** Hence, the awfully uninformative error message is happening due to a request to *localhost:xxxx* and not to *flame.local.mongohq.com:xxxx*

This will break!

```
defaults: &defaults
  host: localhost  <- THIS 'OVERWRITES' host in the uri!

production:
  <<: *defaults    <- BE CAREFUL WITH WHAT YOU BRING IN. THE host: FROM DEFAULTS WILL BE THE ONE APPLIED, not your uri host.
  uri: <%= ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'] %>
```

fix it with either removing the *host:* in defaults, and/or removing the *<<: *defaults*

---

ORIGINAL Q:

I have added the [mongoHQ](http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2010/4/30/mongohq_add_on_public_beta/) addon for [mongodb](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Rails+3+-+Getting+Started) at heroku. It crashes with :

```
connect_to_master': failed to connect to any given host:port (Mongo::ConnectionFailure)
```

The descriptions online ([heroku mongohq](http://docs.heroku.com/mongohq)) are more directed towards mongomapper, as I see it. I'm running ruby 1.9.1 and rails 3-beta with [mongoid](http://docs.heroku.com/mongohq).

My feeling says that there's something with `ENV['MONGOHQ_URL']`, which it says the MongoHQ addon sets, but I haven't set `MONGOHQ_URL` anywhere in my app. I guess the problem is in my 
mongoid.yml ?

```
defaults: &defaults
  host: localhost

development:
  <<: *defaults
  database: aliado_development

test:
  <<: *defaults
  database: aliado_test

# set these environment variables on your prod server
production:
  <<: *defaults
  host: <%= ENV['MONGOID_HOST'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['MONGOID_PORT'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['MONGOID_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['MONGOID_PASSWORD'] %>
  database: <%= ENV['MONGOID_DATABASE'] %>
```

It works fine locally, but fails at heroku, more stack trace:

```
==> crashlog.log <==
Cannot write to outdated .bundle/environment.rb to update it
/disk1/home/slugs/176479_b14df52_b875/mnt/.bundle/gems/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack.rb:14: warning: already initialized constant VERSION
/disk1/home/slugs/176479_b14df52_b875/mnt/.bundle/gems/gems/mongo-0.20.1/lib/mongo/connection.rb:435:in `connect_to_master': failed to connect to any given host:port (Mongo::ConnectionFailure)
    from /disk1/home/slugs/176479_b14df52_b875/mnt/.bundle/gems/gems/mongo-0.20.1/lib/mongo/connection.rb:112:in `initialize'
    from /disk1/home/slugs/176479_b14df52_b875/mnt/.bundle/gems/gems/mongoid-2.0.0.beta4
/lib/mongoid/railtie.rb:32:in `new'
    from /disk1/home/slugs/176479_b14df52_b875/mnt/.bundle/gems/gems/mongoid-2.0.0.beta4/lib/mongoid/railtie.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /disk1/home/slugs/176479_b14df52_b875/mnt/.bundle/gems/gems/mongoid-2.0.0.beta4/lib/mongoid.rb:110:in `configure'
    from /disk1/home/slugs/176479_b14df52_b875/mnt/.bundle/gems/gems/mongoid-2.0.0.beta4/lib/mongoid/railtie.rb:21:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from /disk1/home/slugs/176479_b14df52_b875/mnt/.bundle/gems/gems/railties-3.0.0.beta3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
.....
```

It all works locally, both tests and app. I'm out of ideas... Any suggestions?

PS: Somebody with high repu mind create the tag 'mongohq'?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Mongoid (master) now has a URI option in mongoid.yml. So you could do:

```
production:
  uri: <%= ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'] %>
```

To use mongoid master in your project, set this in your Gemfile

```
gem "mongoid", :git => "git@github.com:mongoid/mongoid.git"
```

Hopefully a new gem will be released soon which will clean things up.

Comment: The uri fix doesn't seem to work yet. I found the ticket/issue at github.com/durran/mongoid and the source of it http://ragingonrails.com/post/566548996/using-mongoid-on-heroku-with-mongohq . I did it the same way, manipulating the ENV for port, host and so on. That worked!

Comment: This answer is marked a correct. For others experiencing the same, note that I had to tweek some myself. It should also be `:git => git://github.com/durran/mongoid.git`

Comment: Now need to use `production > sessions > default > uri` - updated the answer to match.

Answer (score 11):

It seems to me that specifying host in the defaults hash overrides the value in uri.
To fix it just remove the host from the default, here is my config/mongo.yml:

```
defaults: &defaults
  allow_dynamic_fields: true
  parameterize_keys: true
  persist_in_safe_mode: true
  raise_not_found_error: true
  reconnect_time: 3
  use_object_ids: true

production:
  <<: *defaults
  uri: <%= ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'] %>
```

Here is the snippet from mongoid's config.rb:

```
  mongo_uri = settings["uri"].present? ? URI.parse(settings["uri"]) : OpenStruct.new

  name = settings["database"] || mongo_uri.path.to_s.sub("/", "")
  host = settings["host"] || mongo_uri.host || "localhost" # <= look here
  port = settings["port"] || mongo_uri.port || 27017
```

Answer (score 4):

We have some mongoid docs on our heroku section of our docs.  They haven't been released officially yet but you can get it to it already.  Don't expect much in the way of styles and content yet, but it does have some info that you might find useful for mongoid.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mongohq

Answer (score 0):

Just a note that this works for me without any issues, as advertised on http://mongoid.github.com/docs/installation/

Gemfile:

```
gem "rails", '3.0.0.beta3'
gem "mongoid", "2.0.0.beta4"
gem "bson_ext", "0.20.1"
```

mongoid.yml:

```
host: xxx.mongohq.com
port: xxx
database: db
username: user
password: xxx
```

Comment: how do you know what to put instead of xxx, when deploying to heroku? Are you not using the MongoHQ heroku addon?