# Ruby Sinatra - connect to mongoDB on mongoHQ failed

Tags: ruby, mongodb, sinatra, heroku, mongomapper

This is just for my weekend project/study, I am very new to Sinatra and MongoDB.

I've installed the gems for mongoDB, such as: mongo, mongo_mapper and mongoid.

When I tried connecting to my database on MongoHQ from localhost, it encountered such an error:

```
Mongo::ConnectionFailure at /
failed to connect to any given host:port

    * file: connection.rb
    * location: connect
    * line: 489
```

I found [a similar thread on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784417/heroku-mongohq-and-mongoid-mongoconnectionfailure), but frankly speaking, I don't quite understand the answers...

Here is my code snippet:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'mongo'
require 'mongo_mapper'

get '/' do
  MongoMapper.connection = Mongo::Connection.new('flame.mongohq.com', 27044)
  MongoMapper.database = 'notes'
  MongoMapper.database.authenticate('foo', 'bar')
  erb :list
end
```

I took the above code from [here](http://support.mongohq.com/faqs/how-tos/connect-to-mongohq-with-mongomapper), but it seems not working...

Which part is wrong? Is there another way to do this? In the end this test web app will be deployed onto heroku, so I hope the solution can work with both localhost and my heroku server.

Updated:

```
I just created a minimal code snippet to test the mongodb connection:
require 'rubygems'
require 'mongo'

db = Mongo::Connection.new("flame.mongohq.com", 27044).db("notes")
```

But still got the error, after timeout:

```
$ ruby mongodbtest.rb 
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mongo-1.0.8/lib/../lib/mongo/connection.rb:489:in
`connect': failed to connect to any given host:port (Mongo::ConnectionFailure)
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mongo-1.0.8/lib/../lib/mongo/connection.rb:137:in
`initialize'
from mongodbtest.rb:4:in `new'
from mongodbtest.rb:4
```

The hostname and port are according to mongoHQ documentation, so they must be right.

Thanks for the help in advance.

**2nd Update**:

I just tested the mongodb connection string using terminal:

```
mongo mongodb://flame.mongohq.com:27044/notes -u foo -p bar
```

Unfortunately this would get me an connection failed error, honestly, I don't know why...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use

```
uri =  URI.parse(ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'])
@mongo_connection = Mongo::Connection.from_uri( uri )
@mongo_db = @mongo_connection.db(uri.path.gsub(/^\//, ''))
@mongo_db.authenticate(uri.user, uri.password)
```

You can look up your mongo url using the `heroku config --long` command

Answer (score 0):

Just gave this another try, this time, I was using the ip address taken from ping:

So, if I change :

```
db = Mongo::Connection.new('flame.mongohq.com', 27060).db("notes")
db.authenticate('fake', 'info')
```

To:

```
db = Mongo::Connection.new('184.73.224.5', 27060).db("notes")
db.authenticate('fake', 'info')
```

That will work...

I still don't understand why the domain name approach won't work, but at least I can finish this off :)