# MongoID, Heroku, MongoLab/HQ, w/o addons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I currently want to test out heroku mongoid mongolab/mongohq.

however, i don't want to work with heroku addons, instead, i want to config mongoid to directly use a mongolab/mongohq database via uri oder other settings. However, this doesn't really work out well.

Heres what i've done so far:

```
rails new test-mongoid --skip-active-record
```

Gemfile

```
gem 'mongoid'
gem 'haml'
gem 'sass'

rails g mongoid:config
```

scaffolded a test model

```
rails g scaffold Article title:string body:string
```

mongoid.yml

```
production:
  host: <%= ENV['MONGOID_HOST'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['MONGOID_PORT'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['MONGOID_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['MONGOID_PASSWORD'] %>
  database: <%= ENV['MONGOID_DATABASE'] %>
```

other try already did with mongoid.yml

```
production:
  uri: mongodb://<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<database>
```

filled in with my username password etc.

tested it locally with a mongodb, everything worked fine. pushed it to heroku, does not work.

anyone already did it this way to bypass those heroku addons and know how to handle it?

sincerely,
cschaeffler

**EDIT**

configured my mongoid.yml like this

```
production:
  sessions:
    default:
      hosts:
        - <server>:<port>
      username: <username>
      password: <password>
      database: <dbname>
```

seems to be running... but if i try to go to the scaffolded Article index
app.herokuapp.com/articles

i get

```
[2012-08-18 21:54:30] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2012-08-18 21:54:30] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux]
[2012-08-18 21:54:30] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=57443
State changed from starting to up
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.1 application starting in production on http:// 0.0. 0.0:57443
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
=> Call with -d to detach
Started GET "/articles" for 79.199.52.102 at 2012-08-18 21:54:31 +0000
Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 264ms
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
11: 
10:   </tr>

14:     <td><%= article.title %></td>
15:     <td><%= article.body %></td>
13:   <tr>
Rendered articles/index.html.erb within layouts/application (208.2ms)
9:     <th></th>
12: <% for article in @articles %>
app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:7:in `index'

app/views/articles/index.html.erb:12:in    _app_views_articles_index_html_erb__1324099721200765517_18939540'

cache: [GET /articles] miss
GET safe-atoll-7856.herokuapp.com/articles dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=342ms status=500 bytes=643
Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
Process exited with status 137
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? The MongoHQ addon for heroku is just like every other MongoHQ database, it just creates a MONGOHQ_URL Heroku config when you add it.

Comment: Are you using Mongoid 3.x? If so, what version of Ruby are you running and on what Heroku stack are you running on. Can you let us know what error you are seeing in your stack? Jason MongoHQ

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
ruby '1.9.3'
```

to your `Gemfile`.  From [Mongoid 3 + Heroku (MongoHQ) cause Moped::Errors::OperationFailure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494134/mongoid-3-heroku-mongohq-cause-mopederrorsoperationfailure)

You might expect this to just work if you're using Ruby 1.9.3 locally, but no.

Comment: Great catch @Leopd, i ve been struggling with this for more than a hour.. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

In your `mongoid.yml`:

```
production:
  host: your_host.mongohq.com
  port: 10078
  username:your_user_name
  password: your_pass
  database: your_db_name
```

So actually, what you're doing is fine, should just be the values which are invalid or in an improper format