# Heroku nil class error while saving an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, mongoid, delayed-job

I have an application on heroku which uses mongoid and delayed_job and i have changed the ruby version from 1.9.2 to 1.9.3 I am getting an error

```
undefined method `match' for nil:NilClass
```

while I try to save an object to mongoid data base my mongoid.yaml file looks like

```
production:
  sessions:
    default:
      uri: <%= ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'] %>
      options:
        skip_version_check: true
        safe: true
```

the trace is here

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `match' for nil:NilClass
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-3.0.13/lib/mongoid/sessions/mongo_uri.rb:49:in `initialize'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-3.0.13/lib/mongoid/sessions/factory.rb:103:in `new'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-3.0.13/lib/mongoid/sessions/factory.rb:103:in `parse'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-3.0.13/lib/mongoid/sessions/factory.rb:62:in `create_session'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-3.0.13/lib/mongoid/sessions/factory.rb:43:in `default'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-3.0.13/lib/mongoid/sessions.rb:109:in `default'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-3.0.13/lib/mongoid/sessions.rb:378:in `__session__'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-3.0.13/lib/mongoid/sessions.rb:213:in `mongo_session'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-3.0.13/lib/mongoid/sessions.rb:157:in `collection'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-3.0.13/lib/mongoid/sessions.rb:25:in `collection'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-3.0.13/lib/mongoid/persistence/operations.rb:27:in `collection'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-3.0.13/lib/mongoid/persistence/operations/insert.rb:27:in `block in persist'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-3.0.13/lib/mongoid/persistence/insertion.rb:25:in `block (2 levels) in prepare'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in `_run__4034630009416245289__create__685777988298500290__callbacks'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_create_callbacks'

... 2 levels...
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-3.0.13/lib/mongoid/persistence/insertion.rb:24:in `block in prepare'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in `_run__4034630009416245289__save__685777988298500290__callbacks'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_save_callbacks'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-3.0.13/lib/mongoid/callbacks.rb:114:in `run_callbacks'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-3.0.13/lib/mongoid/persistence/insertion.rb:23:in `prepare'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-3.0.13/lib/mongoid/persistence/operations/insert.rb:26:in `persist'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-3.0.13/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:50:in `insert'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-3.0.13/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:79:in `save'
from (irb):2
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
```

any one can help me out? thanks in advance

Comment: What is the traceback reporting? What file is this error occurring in?

Comment: I have updated the question with traceback

Comment: Hmm... according to your traceback, for whatever reason, it looks like Heroku thinks you're on Ruby 1.9.1. Any ideas why that might be? This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943470/heroku-not-using-the-specified-ruby-1-9-3

Comment: i have checked with heroku run ruby -v its returning ruby 1.9.3p448

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is happening because the input parameter to this method https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/v3.0.13/lib/mongoid/sessions/mongo_uri.rb#L49 is nil.

Looking further back up the call stack to find out where this string comes from (see https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/v3.0.13/lib/mongoid/sessions/factory.rb#L103) it looks like your `uri` config param is nil. The uri key is present but empty, so can you check your `MONGOHQ_URL` configuration param by running `heroku config`. This should have been set by the MongoHQ addon.

The Ruby 1.9.1 paths in the stack trace are not anything to worry about. See [Why Do Heroku Stack Traces indicate Ruby 1.9.1 is in use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15296990/why-do-heroku-stack-traces-indicate-ruby-1-9-1-is-in-use)

Comment: This should have been automatically configured when you add the MongoHQ addon. You can check whether the addon is still attached to your application with `heroku addons` and if you need to set the config param manually with `heroku config:set KEY=VALUE`. You would have to find the correct URL for your addon through the addons page for your app on the Heroku site.

Comment: is this addon available for free?